# Почему нельзя передать информацию с одной формы на другую C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

Я изначально делал так: создал форму, из которой вызывал бы другую и передавал в нее данные. После чего там поместил 2 TextBox и кнопку. По нажатию кнопки в переменные записывали значения.

```
class Form1 
   {
        public int begin;
        public int end;
        public int size;

      private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
        int a = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        int b = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
        int c = int.Parse(textBox3.Text);
        new Form2().n = c;
        new Form2().begin = a;
        new Form2().end = b;

        begin = a;
        end = b;
        size = c;
        new Form2().Show();
      }
    public int GetBegin()
    {
        return begin;
    }
    public int GetEnd()
    {
        return end;
    }
    public int GetSize()
    {
        return size;
    }
```

Я новичок в изучении C#. Так вот почему не передаются значения? Использование методов Get также не дают эффектов. begin & end используются потом как аргументы для рандома, а size используется для матрицы.

Comment: Решений у данного вопроса может быть масса, начиная от подписки на евенты изминения свойств на вашей второй форме с первой формы, и заканчивая передачей через статические переменные которые живут у вас на глобальном уровне.

Comment: Можете привести конкретную реализацию?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Данные передаются, то Вы при каждой передаче создаете новый экземпляр формы `Form1` и передаете данные, и при отображении опять же создаете новую форму (у нее данных нет, т.к. они переданы другим). Нужно сделать вот так:

```
 Form1 form = new Form1().n = c;
 form.begin = a;
 form.end = b;
 form.size = c;
 form.Show();
```

Почитайте про ООП, хотя бы основы и подобные вопросы отпадут.

P.S. Мне кажется для передачи параметров в дочернюю форму лучше воспользоваться конструктором